# In a Chrome extension how to check if active requests exists?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to check if active requests exists in a Chrome extension.

Is there any way to check using chrome.webRequest or any such way?

Answer (score 0):

I assume, by active requests, you mean the requests which have not finished yet.

There is no direct method available on `chrome.webRequest` API, but there are a few lifecycle events which you may listen to keep track of unfinished requests.

- **onSendHeaders** - this is when the request is finally sent from the browser
- **onCompleted** - this is when the request has been processed successfully
- **onErrorOccurred** - then is when the request failed to process

In each of these listeners, you will receive `requestId` for each request.

```js
const activeRequests = {};

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener((details) => {
  activeRequests[details.requestId] = details;
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]});

chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener((details) => {
  delete activeRequests[details.requestId];
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]});

chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener((details) => {
  delete activeRequests[details.requestId];
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]});
```

Please see https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/ for reference.